# Is there any unit for 3D touch force?

Tags: ios, swift, 3dtouch

From Apple documentation and other questions of SO I got the idea that, for 3D touch we got two values `force` and `maximumPossibleForce`. Which has a range from `0.00 - 6.66...7`.

I am wondering, is there any other unit for this `force` or just **Newton**?

Answer (score 1):

I think the unit is undocumented.

But in any case I prefer to ignore the unit and work with the nice, normalised unit-less quantity given by dividing `force` by `maximumPossibleForce`.

It has all I need: a nice linear range between a little (0) and a lot (1) of pressure.

Although if you suspect it's Newtons then you [should be able to get a `force` of 1 by placing a suitably conducting ~100g object on the screen](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_(unit)) .